# Images are disappearing after refreshing the page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display the data and image using a component.First time the data and images appears but when i refresh the page then data and images both disappear.

This is by component Team.js

```
import React from 'react';
const Team = (props)=>{
    
    return(
        <>
            <h1>{props.data.name}</h1>
            <img name="photo" src={require(`../images/${props.data.image}`)}/>
        </>
    )
}

export default Team;
```

My component is present in components folder and images are present in images folder.

Comment: Do you have any console logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

require usually does not work with string literals (template strings). In other words, the location needs to be known at compile time.

I see two solutions.

**1. Store your images in the public/images folder, and reference them using your website URL (Preferable)**

Lets say you store all your image in the `public/images` folder. We can get the public url of the website using

`var imageBasePath = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/images/";`

this will then allow us to use this to reference our public images in the src for an img tag.

`<img name="photo" src={imageBasePath + props.data.image} />`

where image is the actual name of the image located in the public/images folder.

your team component would look like this

```
const Team = (props) => {

  var imageBasePath =
  window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/images/";


  return (
    <>
      <h1>{props.data.name}</h1>
      <img name="photo" src={imageBasePath + props.data.image} />
    </>
  );
};
```

**2. Store required images in an array and reference by index, export as an object.**

Probably not the preferable method, as working with indexes can be tricky.

```
export const imageList = [
  require("./checklist.jpg"),
  require("./question.jpg"),
  require("./test-pattern.jpg")
];
```

and then the Team implementation

```
import { imageList } from "./Images/imageList";

export const TeamRequire = (props) => {
  let image = imageList[props.data.id];

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{props.data.name}</h1>
      <img name="photo" src={image} />
    </>
  );
};
```

to ease the index issue, we can store and fetch them by objectKey instead

```
export const imageListObj = {
  checkList: require("./checklist.jpg"),
  question: require("./question.jpg"),
  testPattern: require("./test-pattern.jpg")
};

import { imageListObj } from "./Images/imageList";

export const TeamRequireObj = (props) => {
  let image = imageListObj[props.data.imageId];

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{props.data.name}</h1>
      <img name="photo" src={image} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is a codesandbox with the three concepts.

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-rosalind-2xhj67?file=/src/App.js